# How do I disable System Integrity Protection (SIP) AKA "rootless" on macOS?

Tags: macos, sip

Apple has introduced [System Integrity Protection](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899), also known as "rootless", with OS X 10.11, El Capitan. I understand this is a step for general protection against malware but as a developer I need write access to some of the files it locks away.

How do I disable this protection?

Comment: Even though you can fix all SIP aspects, there are plenty entries for this - remember that by compromising the system, you are building stuff that may not run on your client's machine, where SIP is turned on, and users will not accept turning it off

Comment: @Motti Shneor - However, in some cases this needs to be turned of just to have write access to install some SDKs for development purposes. This would not require the client to do the same.

Comment: I came from unix background, trying to understand the logic of rootless: is it because the computer is mostly likely to be single user machine, everything will be installed in the user home directory, so that there is not need to mess with the system directory such as /usr/share/vim/.

Comment: The premise of this question is incorrect. As a developer, you emphatically do *not* need to write to the files it locks away.

Answer (score 166, accepted):

## Note: disabling System Integrity Protection is dangerous, and makes your system more vulnerable to malware.

As Apple puts it in the [developer documentation about SIP](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/disabling_and_enabling_system_integrity_protection):

> ### Warning
>
> Disable SIP only temporarily to perform necessary tasks, and reenable it as soon as possible. ***Failure to reenable SIP when you are done testing leaves your computer vulnerable to malicious code.***

If you are simply trying to configure system development tools such as `vim`, [`python2`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/macos-release-notes/macos-12_3-release-notes#Python), `ruby` and so on, you almost certainly want to be just installing community-maintained versions from [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) and configuring those instead.  The system-provided tools may be convenient to bootstrap, but if you require SIP exceptions for your daily workflow you are almost certainly doing things in a way which will break in a future version of the operating system, and may break applications and other system functionality in the meanwhile.

Valid reasons to disable SIP yourself might be:

- if you're doing research on malware yourself in a disposable environment, such as in a macOS virtual machine
- if you are attempting to modify core operating system functionality for deployment in a highly-specialized environment such as a public-facing kiosk
- if you require a legacy kernel extension such as MacFUSE on an M1 mac

Also important beyond the security implications is the fact that anything you do on a mac with SIP disabled will not work on anyone *else's* mac unless they also disable it first. If you're developing mac apps, then your system becomes less useful as a testbed because you don't know if your code only works because you hacked your system. If you're developing for another platform such as deployment to a web server, then you can't share your development environment setup with other developers on your team without compromising their security as well.

## Here's how to do it if you *really* need to:

Apple's documentation covers disabling SIP, [About System Integrity Protection on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899) and [Configuring System Integrity Protection](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/System_Integrity_Protection_Guide/ConfiguringSystemIntegrityProtection/ConfiguringSystemIntegrityProtection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016462-CH5-SW1).

[An article on lifehacker.com](http://lifehacker.com/how-to-fix-os-x-el-capitans-annoyances-1733836821) lists these steps:

> 1. Reboot your Mac into Recovery Mode by restarting your computer and holding down <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> until the Apple logo appears on your screen.
> 2. Click Utilities > Terminal.
> 3. In the Terminal window, type in `csrutil disable` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
> 4. Restart your Mac.

You can verify whether a file or folder is restricted by issuing this `ls` command using the capital O (and not zero 0) to modify the long listing flag:

```
ls -lO /System /usr
```

Look for the **restricted** text to indicate where SIP is enforced.

By default (=SIP enabled), the following folders are restricted (see [Apple Support page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899)):

```
/System
/usr
/bin
/sbin
Apps that are pre-installed with OS X
```

... and the following folders are free:

```
/Applications
/Library
/usr/local
```

Comment: I see from running `ls -lO /usr/local` is not marked restricted. I've also chownd `/usr/local/` recursively. But I keep seeing root take ownership of `/usr/local/bin` and `/usr/local/share` which impacts homebrew. Is this the work of SIP as well?

Comment: @SaxDaddy As long as `/usr/local` is not restricted, you can fix any permissions "below" this directory easily. Homebrew actually recommends to run `sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local` (while being logged in as an admin user) to fix permission issues.

Comment: @patrix Thanks. I'm still curious because `/usr/local` is **not** restricted and chown'd by me *daily*. Still each day I see those same 2 folders owned by root. I'll troll the console and update if I find the culprit.

Comment: As a sidenote:  if you ever want to re-enable SIP, just follow those same instructions, replacing `csrutil disable` with `csrutil enable`.

Comment: @SaxDaddy Are you using Sophos Anti-Virus, by some chance? There is a known issue with Sophos where it changes permissions on those directories.  According to [a thread on their community forums](https://community.sophos.com/products/free-antivirus-tools-for-desktops/f/17/t/10029), it should be resolved in an update due out "soon".

Comment: @NDGeek: +1: Brilliant, thank you! You called it correctly. And I see that SAV 9.4.1 (released 18nov15) fixed the problem. I have that version installed and confirmed that `/usr/local` now has permissions set correctly.

Comment: @SaxDaddy Good to know that was your issue, and that the update resolved it! I'm on a corporate network that hosts the updates locally, so I'm still waiting :-/

Comment: this saved me a day... searching on the VMWARE error turned up nothing

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thanks. Very useful to know.

Comment: There is no -O option to ls on El Capitan 10.11.6. What is the equivalent under this OS version? [And I checked - I ma using O and not zero.]

Comment: @andro The -O flag _does_ still work in 10.11.6. If it doesn't work for you, that's a separate issue and you should ask a new question.

Comment: @Mike Scott thanks for twigging me onto this. I was not conscious of using /usr/local/bin/ls (GNU coreutils) as opposed to /bin/ls. That's the explanation.

Comment: Just to add, make sure you use the top level directory, e.g. `ll -O /usr`, not `ll -O /usr/local`.

Comment: To confirm SIP is disabled run `csrutil status`

Comment: For Catalina, even after disabling csrutil, the volumes are unwritable. Use the following in order to write to /Systems/: "sudo mount -uw /"

Comment: @Manish Using Monterey the volumes are indeed still unwritable after disabling SIP but using your suggested command `sudo mount -uw /` results in the error message: `mount_apfs: volume could not be mounted: Permission denied
mount: / failed with 66`

Answer (score 130):

It's possible to disable SIP by booting to **Recovery HD** and running the following command:

```
csrutil disable
```

[image]

It is also possible to enable SIP protections and selectively disable aspects of it, by adding one or more flags to the `csrutil enable` command. All require being booted from Recovery in order to set them:

**Enable SIP and allow installation of unsigned kernel extensions**

```
csrutil enable --without kext
```

[image]

**Enable SIP and disable filesystem protections**

```
csrutil enable --without fs
```

[image]

**Enable SIP and disable debugging restrictions**

```
csrutil enable --without debug
```

[image]

**Enable SIP and disable DTrace restrictions**

```
csrutil enable --without dtrace
```

[image]

**Enable SIP and disable restrictions on writing to NVRAM**

```
csrutil enable --without nvram
```

[image]

I also have a post available with more information about SIP:

[System Integrity Protection – Adding another layer to Apple’s security model](https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2015/10/01/system-integrity-protection-adding-another-layer-to-apples-security-model/)

Comment: What a welcome wealth of knowledge. I might have to double down on this bounty :-)

Comment: I get an error: `csrutil: failed to modify system integrity configuration.  This tool needs to be executed from the Recovery OS.`

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky Read the answer. **'_disable SIP by booting to Recovery HD_'**.

Comment: i disable it and cant edit my ssh.plist

Answer (score 17):

If the goal is to really just disable System Integrity Protection then booting into the Recovery HD partition as previously recommended in the other answers here via <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> on boot is **not** the fastest way to do this.

You can combine single user mode boot with recovery HD boot in an undocumented startup key combination:

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904 covers normal recovery
- hold <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> to boot into Single User Recovery Mode.

This gets you just into the bare minimum environment that is needed for this **directly**.

Answer (score 8):

It would be safer to modify `/etc/paths` so that `/usr/local/bin` is merely before `usr/bin`. That way you can do your development work within `/usr/local/bin` without having to disable SIP.

Clean installations of the OS have ordered `/etc/paths` this way since El Capitan, but if you were upgrading the OS from Yosemite or earlier, you'd have to modify the path order manually.

Comment: @iconoclast Before El Capitan, a common convention was to install programs to `usr/bin`. Since SIP prevents this now, programs should be installed to `usr/local/bin`, which isn’t restricted by SIP. By putting `usr/local/bin` first, users can run programs without having to type out the absolute path to the program. Does this make sense? Are you confused about something else?

Comment: I've always understood it to be a very bad practice to put anything in `/usr/bin`... but I guess what I should have asked is "how does this answer OP's question?"  I was originally assuming that it _did_ in some way, and that I just wasn't making the connection.  But now I'm very doubtful that it has any connection.

Comment: @iconoclast I think it would be irresponsible not to mention to a developer that they really shouldn’t be disabling SIP just to develop an app.

Answer (score 6):

If all you need is to access /usr/local, take a look at this page: http://web.archive.org/web/20160117204214/https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/El_Capitan_and_Homebrew.md

The idea is to *temporarily* disable SIP using `csrutil disable`, add `/usr/local`, use chflags to set that directory to non-restricted

```
 sudo mkdir /usr/local && sudo chflags norestricted /usr/local && sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local
```

and then re-enable SIP using `csrutil enable`.

If `/usr/local` already exists at the time of your upgrade, then even the above isn't necessary. You can simply run

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local
```

Comment: I keep getting an error: `Read-only file system`

Comment: This link is dead: 404 error.

Comment: Fixed dead link.

Comment: This is no longer needed, since /usr/local is not protected by SIP anymore.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't get into *Recovery Partition* to run `csrutil disable` (to disable [SIP](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204899)), try setting boot args with `nvram` command, e.g.

```
sudo nvram boot-args="rootless=0"
```

However, if you've got the following error:

> nvram: Error setting variable - 'boot-args': (iokit/common) not permitted

then it won't work. You still need to boot it recovery/safe mode.

See:

- [Setting a NVRAM variable in normal boot not permitted but allowed in recovery mode](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/315120/22781)
- [Restarting in safe mode without using the shift key under Mojave](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/341681/22781)

Comment: ```nvram: Error setting variable - 'boot-args': (iokit/common) not permitted```

Comment: @mghicks In that case, it won't work. I've updated the answer.