# Can't write to /usr/lib

Tags: permission, macos, sudo

I upgraded to OS X El Capitan and tried to install a new app (MPLAB X from Microchip) but I got an error because it couldn't copy a library to `/usr/lib` even when it asked for root password. I tried to manually copying the library using `sudo cp libSEGGERAccessLink.dylib /usr/lib` but it says `cp: /usr/lib/libSEGGERAccessLink.dylib: Operation not permitted`.

Is this a permission issue? How can I write to `/usr/lib`?  `ls -ld /usr/lib` returns:

```
drwxr-xr-x  263 root  wheel  8942 Oct  2 15:49 /usr/lib
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It is a new feature of OS X 10.11 (El Capitan): SIP.

> System Integrity Protection (SIP,[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Integrity_Protection) sometimes referred to as rootless[2](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899)) is a security feature of OS X El Capitan, the operating system by Apple Inc.

...

> Among the protected locations are: /System, /bin, /sbin and /usr (but not /usr/local).

[System Integrity Protection on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Integrity_Protection)

It can be disabled:
[Stack Exchange thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-max-os-x-el)

In summary, from the Recovery partition, open Terminal.app and run: `csrutil disable`

...

**Update: SIP has been expanded in High Sierra (macOS 10.13)**

[KB on Apple's Support Site](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899)

Comment: Althoiugh in this case I would ask Microchip what to do as if they do support OSX 10.11 they should give a solution - if it is as this answr they don't really support OSX 10.11 and there might be other issues

Comment: True; some products have been using work-arounds or re-writing necessary components.

Comment: @Mark Microchip is aware of the issue and we are hoping they will fix it in the next release

Comment: @Andres: it seems you are in the loop :) will you do the same with microchip-libraries-for-applications-v2013-06-15-osx? I know it's a deprecated library but we need it for Android development...

Comment: @rokjarc I don't know, didn't use them but I just disabled SIP, installed MPLAB X and enabled it again.

Comment: @Andres: i guess that is the only way at the moment, tnx

Comment: Thanks helped me out after several hours trying to install PsN 4.4.8 under El Capitan. Just shifted the installation to usr/local/bin.

Comment: In monterey on silicon Macs after disabling SIP, the volume `/usr/lib/` is still unwritable.