# Error configuring mcrypt after upgrading to El Capitan

Tags: macos, apache, sip

I am facing the following issue after upgrading to El Capitan. It says:

```
Installing shared extensions: /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/
cp: /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/#INST@826#: Operation not permitted
```

while running sudo make install in mcrypt/php-5.6.13/ext/mcrypt folder.
I think this is due to SIP but what is the other way round.

### What is SIP and how do I know if it's causing this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is due to SIP. So the two options you have are

- [disable SIP entirely](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-max-os-x-el)
- raise a defect/support request against mcrypt to use `/usr/local` instead of `/usr` for installation

Comment: I'm facing the same problem, what's SIP and how do I disable it?

Comment: Please use the search field on top right

Answer (score 6):

After reading @user980575's response (which is a bit redundant with directories) and a comment on [Coolest Guide's On The Planet](https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/install-mcrypt-for-php-on-mac-osx-10-10-yosemite-for-a-development-server/#comment-2450227445)'s post regarding this subject (which requires manually editing your `./configure` script) I came up with an alternative solution. Overriding the `EXTENSION_DIR` on the fly.

It took a little trial and error but when you're ready to actually perform the install after phpizing (is that a word?) simply make the directory:

```
mkdir -p /usr/local/lib/php/extensions
```

And then run:

```
./configure

make

sudo make EXTENSION_DIR='/usr/local/lib/php/extensions' install
```

Now that the extension is placed in a non-protected directory you just have to update your `php.ini` to point to the extension with the full path.

```
extension=/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/mcrypt.so
```

Answer (score 3):

El Capitan adds a new security feature named [System Integrity Protection](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/System_Integrity_Protection_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html) (SIP). Among other things, SIP prevents parties other than Apple from adding, deleting or modifying directories and files stored in certain directories:

```
/bin
/sbin
/usr
/System
```

Apple has indicated that the following directories are available for developers to access:

```
/usr/local
/Applications
/Library
~/Library
```

All directories in `/usr` except for `/usr/local` are protected by SIP.

For more information on SIP, please see this post:

https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2015/10/01/system-integrity-protection-adding-another-layer-to-apples-security-model/

Comment: For those wanting to disable SIP, there's a separate post that discusses this: [http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-max-os-x-el](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-max-os-x-el)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to disable System Integrity Protection to install php extensions. Just create a suitable directory in /usr/local, and use the INSTALL_ROOT variable. e.g.

```
% mkdir -p /usr/local/php56_ext
```

and in your extension directory:

```
% INSTALL_ROOT=/usr/local/php56_ext make install
```

You will need to activate the extension using the full path, so in your php.ini, you will need the line:

```
extension=/usr/local/php56_ext/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/mcrypt.so
```