# How to Install PIL in El Capitan with Pip?

Tags: macos, python

I would like to install PIL by Pip but the code is unsuccessful

```
pip install PIL
Collecting PIL
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PIL (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for PIL
```

I know the outdated thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9070074/54964) about *How can I install PIL on mac os x 10.7.2 Lion*, and my versions should be ok, since they are most updated.
My Pip and Python versions in OS X 10.11.4 El Capitan

```
pip --version
pip 8.1.1 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
```

My pip is installed by `sudo python get-pip.py` of the mother site. 
I have the newest xcode installed

```
gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.29)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

---

How can you install Pil in OS X 10.11.4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because PIL is not setuptools compatible (https://mail.python.org/pipermail/image-sig/2010-August/006480.html) and has as such probably never been installable through pip. I think in general it should be considered deprecated in favor of [Pillow](http://python-pillow.org/) which is an actively developed compatible fork of PIL.

So what you want to do is `pip install Pillow`, and also consider different pip usage since El Capitan like described in another thread [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/209572/how-to-use-pip-after-the-os-x-el-capitan-upgrade).