# How to install pip in OS X El Capitan?

Tags: macos, terminal, finder, command-line, python

I am a new Mac user, and I need help trying to install `pip` in OS X El Capitan.

I ran this command, `python get-pip.py` and ended up with this error:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/folders/hc/87zml1_52jd544j9cd71mqrh0000gn/T/tmp83m3F3/pip.zip/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/var/folders/hc/87zml1_52jd544j9cd71mqrh0000gn/T/tmp83m3F3/pip.zip/pip/commands/install.py", line 317, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/var/folders/hc/87zml1_52jd544j9cd71mqrh0000gn/T/tmp83m3F3/pip.zip/pip/req/req_set.py", line 742, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/var/folders/hc/87zml1_52jd544j9cd71mqrh0000gn/T/tmp83m3F3/pip.zip/pip/req/req_install.py", line 831, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/var/folders/hc/87zml1_52jd544j9cd71mqrh0000gn/T/tmp83m3F3/pip.zip/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1032, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/var/folders/hc/87zml1_52jd544j9cd71mqrh0000gn/T/tmp83m3F3/pip.zip/pip/wheel.py", line 346, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/var/folders/hc/87zml1_52jd544j9cd71mqrh0000gn/T/tmp83m3F3/pip.zip/pip/wheel.py", line 317, in clobber
    ensure_dir(destdir)
  File "/var/folders/hc/87zml1_52jd544j9cd71mqrh0000gn/T/tmp83m3F3/pip.zip/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip'
```

Comment: See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26279207/installing-pip-using-easy-install and definitely use virtual environments - but you should work out if it might be easier to manage with anaconda or a general purpose package system like macports or home-brew

Comment: Also check out http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/209572/how-to-use-pip-after-the-os-x-el-capitan-upgrade

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK if you're a new Mac user you really should start with getting to be acquainted with HomeBrew. Leave the python on the system as it is and use your own Python installation you get from HomeBrew.

See here: http://brew.sh/

Pip is provided if you install python with brew. I can really recommend using pyenv also and if you want to do Python development have a good look at the community variant of PyCharm (https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/).