# .pkg for installer hangs on verify

Tags: install, pkg, verify, sound-volume

I'm trying to install the Mono MDK, and downloaded the .pkg for 4.2.1 (about 200 MB), when I double click on the package, it opens a "verifying xxxxxMDKxxxxx.pkg" window, which does nothing for over an hour while the Installer icon bounces on the dock. Is there a way to bypass the verification or force it to verify? 
Or, alternatively is there a way to install the Mono MDK using the command line? 
I'm running a early 2011 Macbook Pro on OSX 10.11

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Ran into this with some other software, but wanted to pass on [a tip I picked up](https://forums.virtualbox.org/posting.php?mode=quote&f=8&p=359950&sid=bde59defe2be917b02b6aecc5ff364d7).

In finder, launch `/System/Library/CoreServices/Installer.app`. It will prompt you to locate a `.pkg` file to install. Navigate to the `.dmg` volume you've mounted, and select the `xxxxxMDKxxxxx.pkg` file.

Installation should proceed normally from there.

Comment: Why does this happen?

Comment: Not Mono pkg specific - I've seen it twice now (same computer) with Virtualbox. Still no idea what's causing, suspect some bug w/ Gatekeeper.

Comment: Works on El Capitan 10.11.5

Comment: Most probably introduced with El Capitan. Never seen such silly bugs in OS X on previous versions. After descovering a lot of issues in all versions of OS X after Yosemite - I tried to stay on it as long as possible, but unfortunately latest macbook doesn't support earlier versions - now have to heck with this Capitan degradation :(

Answer (score 4):

```
/System/Library/CoreServices/Installer.app
```

For installer:

1. Open the Finder
2. Navigate to Go menu
3. Select the Go to Folder submenu.
4. Copy the file path into it.
5. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
6. Locate the `.dmg` or `.mpkg` package.
7. Voila you are done.

Answer (score 2):

Not a verified answer but I can't comment: try to [disable Rootless System Integrity as indicated here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-os-x-10-11).

Source: [OSXDaily says](http://osxdaily.com/2015/10/17/how-to-install-java-in-os-x-el-capitan/) "Mac users may need to disable rootless SIP protection in OS X before being able to successfully install Java, but you can enable it again after it has been installed. If you get stuck on “verifying…” during the installation process of Java, it’s because of rootless."

Answer (score 1):

For me it was enough to move the .pkg file from the virtual installer drive to my desktop.

Answer (score 0):

This might help

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CG11m8ykuH8&feature=youtu.be

That video worked for me, at least.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  We like answers to be more than just a single line.  Ideally, you want to explain why your answer is *right."  It also helps to provide links, citations, and/or screen shots.  Please review our help section [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on writing good answers to questions