# What is AppSC extremely slowing down my MacBook Pro?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, malware

I noticed that my OS X very frequently runs extremely slow and everything lags. I opened up Activity Monitor and I saw that something called AppSC is using up to 95% of the memory. It makes my computer run very hot. I immediately Force Quit the program when I notice it but it keeps happening.

Does anyone know what AppSC is?

Comment: What is the path to the executable on disk?

Comment: Could you enter the following command in `Terminal`: `launchctl list` and add the output to your original question?

Answer (score 5):

AppSC is malware. Download, install and run the free app [Malwarebytes Anti-Malware for Mac](https://www.malwarebytes.org/antimalware/mac/). It will detect it and you will be asked to remove it (and some other potentially installed malware).

If you can't download/install the anti-malware app because everything is sluggish, you have to move or remove the responsible plist file(s) in /Users/your_user_name/Library/LaunchAgents/, /Library/LaunchAgents/ or /Library/LaunchDaemons/ manually by booting to Single User Mode or to Recovery Mode. Remove the responsible plist file by cd'ing to one of the directories and mv'ing or rm'ing it. I don't remember precisely but I think the file name contains `*.appsc.*` or `*.appscd.*`. If you are running El Capitan you might have to disable [System Integrity Protection](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-os-x-10-11). Then continue booting or reboot to your main volume and try again downloading, installing and running Malwarebytes Anti-Malware for Mac.

---

I recently got hands on a client's iMac infected with AppSC and some other malware. I've suspected MacKeeper (which was "installed" also) as the main culprit but I haven't been able to substantiate my assumption.

To remove the malware I first booted to a thumb drive containing a full OS X Mavericks and then - after investigating modify/create dates of several apps and folders - moving suspicious launch agents/daemons in *~/Library/LaunchAgents*, */Library/LaunchAgents* or */Library/LaunchDaemons* to inert folders like */Library/LaunchDaemons (Off)*. Then I booted to the main volume and installed the aforementioned software and uninstalled/deleted all malware files.

AppSC (accompanied by an *AppSC daemon* which starts AppSC while booting and restarts AppSC after force quitting it) just "eats" RAM with a rate of 50 MB-300 MB/s. Immediately after starting the iMac about 6 GB of 8 GB RAM were free. After all free RAM is gone the whole system swaps with a slightly slower rate. After one minute the client's iMac had a swap size of 4 GB with no other apps running. 
Memory swapping will slow down your OS X and all running regular apps and after a while it's almost impossible to do *anything* even rebooting.

Comment: Great answer! I would suggest you to place all the correct useful PATHes as code so as to avoid missing a character during a copy operation (`~` or `/`).

Comment: @danielAzuelos Since the client was in a hurry and I had to fix this quickly I didn't document this properly. As soon as I find more informations or after infecting one of my VMs with AppSC I will add proper names/paths.

Comment: This is one of the first and excellent documentation about this attack.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever it is, it's definitely not normal and it is caused by 3rd party software. I can't find out anything about it on the internet, so you should probably take your computer into an Apple Store and have them look at it. I would need to see the path to the executable to figure it out. Have you tried force quitting the process?