# Permanently Disabling System Integrity Protection

Tags: macos, sip

I have disabled system integrity protection on El Cap following this [Ask Different question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-os-x-10-11) but it keeps coming back every time I reboot which is annoying.

Is there an extra step I need to perform to stop SIP switching itself back on after reboot?

Comment: I asked a new question https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/361374/permanently-disable-sip?noredirect=1#comment478989_361374 because the wording of your question confused me: "stop SIP switching itself back on after reboot" sounds like SIP is _never_  disabled, but in my case SIP disabled correctly once, but after the next reboot it is enabled again.

Answer (score 5):

There should be no extra step required - in fact, reading through the excellent article linked from that question, I found this…

> Because SIP’s configuration is stored in NVRAM, SIP’s protection settings will apply to the entire machine and will persist even if the OS is reinstalled.

This would perhaps imply your NVRAM is not correctly holding data -
perhaps try a reset,  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>   <kbd>P</kbd>   <kbd>R</kbd>  at the chimes & keep holding until you hear the chimes a second time.

Source : [System Integrity Protection – Adding another layer to Apple’s security model](https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2015/10/01/system-integrity-protection-adding-another-layer-to-apples-security-model/)

If after resetting NVRAM one time, you can’t make SIP status stick the next steps are to repair and wipe your drive and then seek hardware service is a freshly erased and reinstalled OS won’t allow you to disable SIP.