# Permanently disable SIP

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mojave

I disable SIP like this: reboot into recovery mode, run `csrutil disable` and then restart.

Great, now SIP is disabled.

But if my MacBook restarts again, it looks like it is enabled again.

How can I make subsequent restarts not change `csrutil status`?

Comment: So I guess it's a bug

Comment: You said, "So I guess it's a bug", well have you tried resetting NVRAM and then disabling SIP and and an rebooting a time or two to see if it now holds or not across reboots/shutdown/startup? If yes, then all I can say is if I disable SIP it stays disabled across reboots/shutdown/startup and if it doesn't for you, not sure I'd call it a bug, not enough information to classify it, but I'd say it's annoying. FWIW I typically do not disable SIP as I see it as a security feature and if there is something I need to mod, I just do it right from the Recovery HD, no disabling SIP... keep things safe.