# How to create/write file under /usr in OS X 10.11

Tags: macos, security, filesystem

I was going to compile a php extension using phpize, but it reported some files not found. I googled and found some solutions,

> In OS X 10.9, we can make a symbol link from /XCODE_PATH/OS_X_SDK/usr/include to /usr/include

But it seems that OS X 10.11 has some system policy which deny this operation. I even tried to boot in single user mode, but I just got

```
$ sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include /usr/include
Sandbox: ln(14) System policy: deny(1) file-write-create /usr/include
```

Anyone knows how to fix this problem? Your answers or comments will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Read the following: [About System Integrity Protection on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899) and [How do I disable System Integrity Protection (SIP) AKA “rootless” on OS X 10.11, El Capitan?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-os-x-10-11)

Answer (score 2):

You can fight SIP, but probably not for long.

Why not just do it the recommended way and put in `/usr/local/include`