# VirtualBox VERR_ACCESS_DENIED

Tags: macos, virtualbox

I am trying to install Windows 10 on a partition with this Virtualbox method, where I create a vmdk link to the partition and use it as the drive, run the installer and then reboot.

This worked fine on a device running Mavericks, but on one with El Capitan does not work, and prints out a `VERR_ACCESS_DENIED`

```
VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename ~/RawWinDisk.vmdk -rawdisk /dev/disk0 -partitions 1,4
```

This is supposed to make the vmdk file. I did do a `chown` to `/dev/disk0`, **disk0s1** and **disk0s4**. I also tried a `chmod -R 777` on them to see if it helped, but it still did not work. Running command as `sudo` does not work either.

Comment: guessing you hit SIP. Did you try with it off?

Comment: @Tetsujin Please explain what SIP is. I didn't yet meet up with such term

Comment: System Integrity Protection - see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-os-x-10-11

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce this on 5.0.10 r104061 - I don't seem to be wrapping my brain around why the Mac raw devices are being used by the guest OS.

Comment: @Tetsujin Disabling SIP actually did work. Please put it in an answer so this question can be answered

Comment: Ah, glad it helped - putting together a [rather short] answer  :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you may be hitting El Capitan's System Integrity Protection [SIP] which is preventing access..

Borrowed from [How do I disable System Integrity Protection (SIP) AKA "rootless" on OS X 10.11, El Capitan?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-os-x-10-11) ...

Apple's documentation covers disabling SIP, [About System Integrity Protection on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899).

[An article on lifehacker.com](http://lifehacker.com/how-to-fix-os-x-el-capitans-annoyances-1733836821) lists these steps:

> 1. Reboot your Mac into Recovery Mode by restarting your computer and holding down <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> until the Apple logo appears on your screen.
> 2. Click Utilities > Terminal.
> 3. In the Terminal window, type in `csrutil disable` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
> 4. Restart your Mac.

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
sudo chown ${USER} /dev/disk0s4
sudo chmod 660  /dev/disk0s4
chmod 600 ~/RawWinDisk.vmdk
```

after each MacOS restart I need again chown /dev/disk0s4 to start Windows VM normally.

Comment: I had to use `${USER}` and `/dev/disk2`to get my external USB drive with the OSX Install files working.

Comment: What does ${USER} refer to here? Disabling SIP hasn't worked for me so I want to try this instead.

Answer (score 4):

I have been booting my bootcamp partition via vbox since probably OSX Lion.  when SIP came along, I had to adjust my vbox run script to do the chmod's as described elsewhere, but today I had to re-create my pointer VMDK (VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk...) because my drive numbering changed (/dev/diskN) and I could not without temporarily disabling SIP... no chmod'ing would make a difference. After creating the new VMDK, I reenabled SIP, and am back to chmod'ing before virtual startup/after each host reboot.