# Access Raw Disk on Virtualbox with SIP enabled

Tags: catalina, virtualbox, sip

I was reading the [following](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/217391/virtualbox-verr-access-denied?newreg=b927552232fa47a4a6c0958b470b1e74) question and answers but I'm having trouble and hoping someone can help.

I am dual booting Catalina and Windows 10 and would like to boot my Windows disks in Virtual box without permanently disabling SIP. I have 4 VMDKs in my Documents folder and VirtualBox says access denied. I tried to run some chmod and chown commands as described in the linked post but it didn't work. What is the proper way to create and access raw disk VMDKs in virtual box so that I can run the VM with SIP?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. Can you edit the question and add the exact commands you think will not work without SIP being disabled?