# How to remove white borders on dark mode in macOS Catalina?

Tags: macos, mojave, catalina

Ever since I updated to Mojave I hated the fact that they put white borders on every window and on the dock in dark mode like those ones:

[image]

But because of [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/218660/how-can-i-remove-the-borders-from-my-dock) post I was finally able to remove those borders from the Dock by replacing `dockbackgrounddark.png` and `dockbackgrounddarkax.png` from `/System/Library/CoreServices/Dock.app/Contents/Resources` with blank files. I was to happy that it was possible to do that:

**Before:**
[image]

**After**
[image]

I then spent hours of searching through resources so I can find where the borders for the apps are located at but I couldn't find anything and I really want to find them. I would be so thankful if anyone could help find those.

It is possible to adapt / suppress the white border on app windows as well?

Comment: I put +1 since this has great images. I added what I think to be the final question that was left inferred or unsaid. Please refine my edit if the “ask” isn’t clear at the end of your post.

Comment: Those white borders are likely put there by the developer of the app. So to do this you would have to find the images inside the app bundle, which may break the bundle and hence the app itself.

Comment: Hi, this is not correct I am so sorry... The borders are present on every app and window, even in finder ever since macOS Mojave and this is a known thing. My screenshot shows spotify just as an example

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? The white border also bothers me.

Comment: I haven't manage to solve it yet.

Answer (score 1):

This is the system behavior in dark mode, the white border is generated from code. There's no image for it.

More details, for titled windows (NSWindow), all windows get a default white border in dark mode. Unless the app developer explicitly removes the `.titled` style mask or uses a transparent window background color. Users has no way to remove this white board.

Comment: Any way to update this just through the app .plist?

Comment: @chrismarx unfortunately, as far as I know, I don't think there's such way to change the window's default border.