# OS X 10.11 Not able to change the folder permission

Tags: safari, macos, permission

I have root permission but still I am not able to change the folder permission

```
sudo chmod  -R 777 /Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/
chmod: Unable to change file mode on /Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/: Operation not permitted
```

But at the same time I am able to do

```
sudo chmod -R 777  /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/
```

System details:

ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.11.2
BuildVersion:   15C50

Could anybody help in identifying the issue?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Some of the root folders (e.g. /sbin /bin) as well as some application bundles (i.e. Apple apps) are protected by System Integrity Protection even if logged in as *root* or using `sudo`.

If you want to make changes to protected items [disable SIP](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-os-x-10-11), apply the changes and reenable it.