# give read&write permission to only 1 file in folder

Tags: finder, macos, permission

I am trying to manually modify preferences file located at

```
/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist
```

To modify it, I need to give it `read&write` permission. I did that. The problem is that the file is in a folder, for which I cannot change permission (I am admin and I have no access), nor do I want to change permissions to the whole folder for security reasons. I only want to change it for preferences.plist file. How can I achieve this?

These are the pop-ups I get when trying to modify it.

[image]

[image]

Upon modifying permissions to parent folder I get this:

[image]

Comment: It's probably SIP - see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-os-x-10-11

Comment: hmm, I just want to lower the walls for 1 file. Strange that Apple forces disabling for every file..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To allow *user_name* writing to *preferences.plist* add an ACL with:

```
sudo chmod +a "user_name allow write" /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist
```

This changes the output of:

```
ls -laeO /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  - 59715  9 Feb 23:25 /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist
```

to:

```
ls -laeO /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist
-rw-r--r--+ 1 root  wheel  - 59715  9 Feb 23:25 /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist
0: user:user_name allow write
```

but doesn't change the permissions of the superior folder or other files residing in the same folder:

```
drwxr-xr-x  15 root      admin        -             510 24 Mär 17:23 SystemConfiguration
```

To remove the ACL later simply enter:

```
sudo chmod -a "user_name allow write" /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist
```

Comment: I ended up disabling SIP and giving the right permission to parent folder, but this seem like a nice answer.