# A way to test System Integrity Protection SIP (NOT about how to enable/disable)?

Tags: macos, sip

When I first began using 10.11 El Capitan I had to disable SIP in order to run some stuff, and to avoid some crashes. The crashes were probably likely down to some kext I had leftover from older software installations, etc. Not sure.

Is there a **way short of enabling SIP** to test to see if I have impermissible kexts or anything else in the protected areas that will gag the machine? I don't really wanna go through tons of booting iterations in the hopes of finding things that hang or crash the machine.

To rephrase, [this is not about how to enable or disable SIP](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-os-x-10-11), but how to programatically or automate a test to determine status of SIP.

Comment: see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-os-x-10-11?rq=1

Comment: I think we should close as duplicate

Comment: I don't think there's a way to 'test' SIP without enabling/disabling and rebooting a few times.

Comment: Would there be a way to check file permissions to see what would NOT be allowed in the SIP protected folders?

Comment: I can think of several ways - hang tight while I test them - this should stay open IMO.

Answer (score 19):

I know you can check whether SIP is on or off in terminal with this command:

```
csrutil status
```

I think you might be looking for a more detailed analysis though.