# Change Application folder presentation w/out disabling SIP

Tags: finder, macos, sip

I keep my apps organized in the /Application folder by arranging their icon manually.
But in El Capitan, SIP prevents the modification of this folder privileges so I cannot set it to *read and write* for my user and change the presentation options nor arrange icons manually.

I do not really want to disable SIP because of all bugs that seems to happen by doing it (even if I quite manage OS X since a while).

How can I manage to arrange my Apps icons without having to disable SIP?
Thanks

Comment: Can you please tell me what bugs will occur when disabling SIP? I have it disabled and I don't have any problems

Comment: All I can see in Related sidebar for example ;) — but if you tell me that everything's fine disabling it, that could be an option. Even if I'm looking for how not to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't. That's what System Integrity Protection is all about. But keep in mind you can disable it, do your changes and reenable it again. Both steps are described in [How do I disable System Integrity Protection (SIP) AKA “rootless” on OS X 10.11, El Capitan?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-os-x-10-11?rq=1)

Comment: If I disable it, allow my user to read/write /Apps folder and re-enable it, user still gonna have read/write permission on /Apps folder?

Comment: I guess so. (Educated guess!)