# Installing KEXTs properly in 10.11

Tags: kernel-extensions

I just want to verify the following holds true for installing kexts in 10.11 via the shell and that there are no other steps missing:

```
sudo cp -R some.kext (/System)/Library/Extensions/    # Add or remove /System based on location of kext on this and next ones
sudo chown -R root:wheel (/System)/Library/Extensions
# maybe add: `sudo chmod -R 755 (/System)/Library/Extensions/`
sudo touch (/System)/Library/Extensions
```

As I understand it, it may be useful to also do the following as far as the kext caches go in current OS releases:

```
# For /System; not sure of location for /Library centric kexts:
sudo rm -R /System/Library/Caches/com.apple.kext.caches
sudo kextcache -u / # or /Volumes/"Whatever volume name"
```

Fix disk permissions

```
sudo /usr/libexec/repair_packages --repair --standard-pkgs --volume /
# Fix Homebrew folder if you use it:
sudo chown -R "$USER":admin /usr/local
```

Reboot:

```
sudo reboot
```

*NOTE: the process seems to have changed over the last couple years from [this](http://osxdaily.com/2012/01/12/how-to-manually-install-kernel-extensions-in-mac-os-x/) (especially with regards to the kext caches) and I would like to receive verification.

Comment: You may need to disable SIP (partially, at least). See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-os-x-10-11

Comment: Yeah, I very much dislike SIP anyway.  As an advanced *nix user, it is more of a curse than anything.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're looking for here. Are you trying to use `sudo kextload [FILEPATH]` or `sudo kextunload [FILEPATH]`?

Comment: No, this was about trying to permanently install KEXTs such that they are loaded at boot and the kext cache does not get in the way as it has seemingly done from time to time.