# Unistall Realtek USB Ethernet Network Adapter

Tags: mac, usb, ethernet, driver

I would like to uninstall the "Realtek USB Ethernet Network Adapter"
I can find it under System Information -> Software -> Installations in a list but don't know how to get rid of it.

Comment: FYI, [Wikipedia page about the RealTek company](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Realtek).

Answer (score 3):

Check the [Realtek site](https://www.realtek.com/en/) for the latest driver of your USB Ethernet adapter and download it. The driver zip file should contain an uninstall.zip. Unzip this also and double-click the resulting *uninstall.command* file. Enter the admin (root) password and reboot your Mac.

**Using an uninstaller provided with the driver installer is recommended.**

Provided it's a RTL8153 chip you can also pour the following content into a uninstall.command file and execute it:

```
#!/bin/sh
. /etc/rc.common

echo "                                                                  "
echo "Please type the password of \"root\" to Uninstall ..."
FROM=`dirname "$0"`

echo "Removing Apple USB Ethernet Driver..."

sudo kextunload /System/Library/Extensions/IONetworkingFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleRTL815X*.kext
sudo kextunload /Library/Extensions/AppleRTL815X*.kext

sudo rm -rf /System/Library/Extensions/IONetworkingFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleRTL815X*.kext
sudo rm -rf /Library/Extensions/AppleRTL815X*.kext

sudo touch /System/Library/Extensions/
sudo touch /Library/Extensions/

echo "Uninstall Complete."
```

Depending on your system version you have to disable SIP.

In Catalina you have to [disable SIP](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-macos-os-x) in Recovery Mode first and mount the system volume read-write after rebooting: `sudo mount -rw /`. Additionally you have to `chmod +x uninstall.command` and add it to System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Full Disk Access.

Enable SIP after uninstalling the driver!

---

If your kext has a different name (e.g. *AppleUSBRealtek8153Patcher.kext*) or paths have changed, you have to adjust it respectively in the file uninstall.command (e.g. AppleRTL815*.kext). Use at your own risk!

Comment: This fails with the error message `Unable to determine realpath for /System/Library/Extensions/IONetworkingFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleRTL815X*.kext - failing.
Can't create /System/Library/Extensions/IONetworkingFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleRTL815X*.kext.
Unable to determine realpath for /Library/Extensions/AppleRTL815X*.kext - failing.
Can't create /Library/Extensions/AppleRTL815X*.kext.
Uninstall Complete.`

Comment: My system version? I am using macOS Catalina 10.15.3.

Comment: What would be the command for that? I'm having trouble finding it online.

Comment: I actually didn't have the expected driver files. A similar one for me is instead called AppleUSBRealtek8153Patcher.kext, in `/System/Library/Extensions`.

Comment: The uninstaller is in the disk image file downloaded from the Realtek website.

Comment: @user3932000 And this uninstaller doesn't work?