# Can you permanently disable rootless on OS X?

Tags: macos, sip

When booting to recover and running `csrutil disable` it just writes it into the NVRAM, unfortunately I reset the NVRAM very often so it's annoying to have to do that all the time. It's also annoying right now when I need to use something which requires me to turn off SIP when I can't reboot, (I am copying a bunch of files).

Comment: Why are you resetting NVRAM so frequently?

Comment: Do you have any other operating systems installed? What is the model/year of your Mac. Do you want to disable all of SIP or just some of the protections? (See [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-os-x-10-11/209530#209530) for a list of protections.) Do you want to do this transparently so everything appears as a normal boot? Or, do you want a menu giving you a choice?

Comment: SIP's default configuration is to be enabled, unless there are settings in NVRAM that tell it otherwise. Reset NVRAM and those settings get removed (as you've found.) What you're running into is SIP working as intended.

Comment: @RichTrouton I know, that's why I am asking if it is possible to turn it off permanently.

Comment: No. It is not possible to permanently turn off.

Answer (score 1):

The following should be possible.

1. Download and install rEFInd to your EFI partition.
2. Use the Mac Startup Manager to make rEFInd the default system to
   boot to.
3. Configure rEFInd know of OS X and to not search for any other
   operating systems. (This decreases boot time.)
4. Configure rEFInd to operate silently and to boot OS X.
5. Configure rEFInd to disable all or part of SIP before booting OS X.

Normally when you start the Mac, OS X should startup (after first silently booting rEFInd). SIP will be in whatever state you configured rEFInd to set it to.

If you reset NVRAM, then you may have to hold down the option key and instruct the Startup Manager to make rEFInd the default to boot to. I say ***may*** because I am not sure if resetting the NVRAM changes the default operating system to boot to.