# How do I disable/configure macOS Sierra's auto throttling of the CPU for processor intensive tasks

Tags: imac, performance, cpu, macos

I'm using an iMac (late 2015) with an Intel core i7 (quad core) 4GHz CPU with 32GB ram and a 3TB Fusion Drive. I'm a software developer working on a huge codebase that used to take about 30 minutes to build and run unit tests on my beast of a machine. Of course, running the build meant that the CPU usage was up through the roof and the fan working at its fastest speed.

I upgraded to macOS sierra yesterday, and my first attempt to build the project I'm working on took three and a half hours! During this time my computer and fan were as quiet as a sleeping baby.

I did some investigation and found that whenever a process uses too much CPU power to the extent of making the fans audible, in just a couple of seconds I see the CPU usage of this process falling down, and after a few minutes, the fan sound goes down too. It seems that in Sierra a feature was added to make sure that the CPU doesn't overheat by throttling the processor usage for high CPU demand processes automatically.

What I need to know is how to disable/configure this feature, because it's killing my productivity. I really love the *other* great features in Sierra, but I would certainly downgrade if there is no way to disable this auto-throttling.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are a few broad steps from a post on "[Disable OS X kernel_task throttling](https://www.davidschlachter.com/misc/kernel_task)" which you will need to try since I don't have an iMac on hand. Strongly suggest you read the post in detail and also understand potential risks before executing this sequence.

1. Disable **[System Integrity Protection](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899)** so you can make system folder edits with steps at
   [How do I disable System Integrity Protection (SIP) AKA “rootless” on OS X 10.11, El Capitan?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/208481/5663)
2. Boot into single-user mode with `Command-S` sequence
3. Mount the filesystem:
   `fsck -y; mount -uw /`
4. Backup the `IOPlatformPluginFamily.kext` extension
   `rsync -av /System/Library/Extensions/IOPlatformPluginFamily.kext /Users/Shared/`
5. now delete the IOPlatformPluginFamily.kext extension and restart
   `rm -rf /System/Library/Extensions/IOPlatformPluginFamily.kext; shutdown -r now`

If/when you want to restore the configuration,
`rsync -av /Users/Shared/IOPlatformPluginFamily.kext /System/Library/Extensions`

The `/Users/Shared/` location for storing extension is a subjective choice. You can backup in any other safe place (even on an external drive). As long as you can retrieve it when you want to rollback this action.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this soon, and if it works, I'll mark this as the accepted answer

Comment: Worked for me. 59˚C and no slowdowns. Used to get thermal throttling at 45˚C.

Comment: Doesn't this action risk the CPU running at minimal speed, i e it also turns off Turbo?

Comment: Tried this on a water damaged MacBook Pro – same scenario as described in the related article. Unfortunately, it doesn’t seem to fix the throttling issue. The CPU still appears to be capped at 0.8GHz.

Comment: @AlaaNassef did you not mark this as accepted because it failed?

Comment: @iconoclast Seems that I forgot to get back to this. Marked as accepted now. Thanks for the reminder