# Howto see disk I/O utilisation per process - iotop and pidstat not available in Homebrew on macOS

Tags: terminal, command-line, homebrew, activity-monitor

I have the same question [like](https://serverfault.com/questions/169676/howto-check-disk-i-o-utilisation-per-process) this, but for macOS.

There is a GUI solution with Activity Monitor. Any command line alternative? I use latest macOS Sierra.

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

iotop is available in macOS/OS X itself.

iotop relies on dtrace though and you have to [disable SIP](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-os-x-10-11) in systems like El Capitan/Sierra to run dtrace.

Check `man iotop` for options and then execute iotop as root :

```
sudo iotop [-C] [-D|-o|-P] [-j|-Z] [-d device] [-f filename] [-m mount_point] [-t top] [interval [count]]
```

Comment: You can also selectively disable SIP, as discussed [here](https://jeffclayton.wordpress.com/2016/05/01/get-dtrace-and-iotop-back-on-os-x/).

Answer (score 9):

`sudo fs_usage -f diskio`

it's not the same as iotop, but it comes with the OS and you don't have to disable SIP.

From the man pages:

```
The fs_usage utility presents an ongoing display of system call usage information pertaining to filesystem
     activity.  It requires root privileges due to the kernel tracing facility it uses to operate.  By default, the
     activity monitored includes all system processes except the running fs_usage process, Terminal, telnetd, telnet,
     sshd, rlogind, tcsh, csh, sh, and zsh.  These defaults can be overridden such that output is limited to include
     or exclude a list of processes specified by the user.
```

Comment: this is pretty interesting but seems difficult to interpret the output