# How to rename osascript in the administrator privileges dialog?

Tags: terminal, applescript

I have used the command.

```
/usr/bin/osascript -e 'do shell script "echo hello args 2>&1 etc" with administrator privileges'
```

It asks for password saying osascript want to make changes. What I want is, how do I change the word *osascript*?

Answer (score 12):

I found a much better way of doing this, by digging through the Applescript doc on the Apple Developer's Site. I found this release note for  [Applescript in MacOS 10.10](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/AppleScript/RN-AppleScript/RN-10_10/RN-10_10.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000982-CH110-SW1)

It says:

```
do shell script can now specify a custom prompt to use in the password dialog. [15194980]
```

However, it neglects to say *how* you can do that. After some guesswork, I figured out that there's a `prompt` clause that lets you replace `osascript wants to make changes...` with whatever you want when using `do shell script...with administrator privileges` in a script invoked by `osascript`.  For example:

```
osascript -e 'do shell script "ls -l" with prompt "The Great And Powerful OZ " with administrator privileges'
```

generates a dialog box that looks like:
[image]

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: Wow. I have been looking for this all day long. This is a total life saver.

Answer (score 2):

The above methods all require administrator privileges in the first place, but if you are trying to do this as part of a bash script you want to distribute without requiring administrative privileges or extra setup, you could do something like the following:

```
TMP=$(mktemp -d)
pushd "$TMP" > /dev/null 2>&1
/usr/bin/osacompile -e 'do shell script "echo hello args 2>&1 etc" with administrator privileges' -o 'My Cool Name.app'
'My Cool Name.app/Contents/MacOS/applet'
popd
rm -rf "$TMP"
```

This will create a temporary directory, compile the script as an applet, execute it and then delete the temporary directory and applet.

Comment: I'm doing *exactly* that... but I also want to return a value from my AppleScript. I've tried error, return and log, which all return values in the Script Editor, but don't affect $? in the shell. If I use osascript, I can get the return values, but then the dialog box has "osascript" in it instead of "My Cool Name". Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming either El Capitan or Sierra is installed, first disable [SIP](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-os-x-10-11) and boot to your main system again.

Open Terminal and enter:

```
sudo ln /usr/bin/osascript /usr/bin/butterfly
```

Enable SIP again.

Now *butterfly* will ask to make changes after entering

```
/usr/bin/butterfly -e 'do shell script "echo hello args 2>&1 etc" with administrator privileges'
```

Instead of *butterfly* you can use almost any other name. The name shouldn't be the name of an executable already existing on your Mac (especially it **mustn't** be one already existing in your PATH).

So *ls* or *diskutil* is a big NoNo but *[necyria_bellona](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c0/Necyria_bellona_manco_NovaraExpZoologischeTheilLepidopteraAtlasTaf36.jpg)* is OK.

---

**This doesn't work for APFS volumes (High Sierra and later) , because hard links don't exist in this file system.**

Comment: You can also just make the hard link to a location that doesn't need the use of `sudo` or disabling SIP. Then use the hard links pathname.

Comment: I tried this before reading your comment (both linking and copying), and it did not work. I am using High Sierra, so this may have been disabled in newer releases, but this is not a reliable or valid option. The accepted answer did the trick for me.

Comment: @klanomath hmm, seems you are correct that no answer has been accepted. Strange! I guess I just looked at the highest-voted answer and my brain just thought it had been accepted for some reason. That's the method I am using to accomplish this. But yeah, requiring a reboot and  having a user disable SIP from recovery or single user would be a tough sell on this. Lol. Also, could you clarify in your answer why disabling SIP is required? I thought it only protected files in /System. Obviously I could be wrong though. I usually disable SIP for various reasons.

Comment: @rubynorails The list of SIP-protected items is **much** longer (e.g `cat /System/Library/Sandbox/rootless.conf`). In High Sierra even some disk blocks seems to be protected (e.g block0=MBR/pMBR). `ls -lO  /usr/bin/ | grep restricted`.