# Creating a directory in /home on MacOS Sierra

Tags: macos

I have this PHP old legacy code that I have inherited. There is hardcode references to /home/project everywhere I can not change them.

I am on MacOS/Sierra and it will not let me create a folder in /home

> sudo mkdir /home/myproj
>
> mkdir: /home/myproj: Operation not supported

I am not new to Linux but new to MacOS

I tried sudo as well and still will not let me.

I also thought maybe a symlink but still not allowed.

[I tried disabling SIP](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-os-x-10-11)

```
$ csrutil status
System Integrity Protection status: disabled.
```

I still get the same error

```
mkdir: /home/foo: Operation not supported
```

Comment: Since you can’t change the scripts - I’ll link this to an article on how to disable SIP. Even root can’t bypass folders protected thusly.

Comment: i followed the steps to disable SIP. Still same issue.
i also updated the description to reflect the changes

Comment: Let’s get this reopened. Perhaps it’s as simple as `sudo mkdir -p /home/foo` one time after you’ve loosened the SIP shackles.

Comment: The scripts I would guess assume some forms of Linux is /home how do you know that the /home is the only place they have assumed that. You need to look and change all the code to check it safely runs on Unix eg macros

Answer (score 13, accepted):

IIRC /home and /net can be used by directory services like AD or OD. They are mount points created by the auto_master file. Usually they are not used for anything - especially on non-corporate Macs.

---

Comment out the line */home         auto_home   -nobrowse,hidefromfinder* in the file */etc/auto_master* and enter `sudo automount -vc` or reboot.

Then you should be able to create /home and any further subdir with `sudo mkdir -p /home/subdir`.

If you are done with your PHP legacy code remove the folder /home and its content and restore the old auto_master file by uncommenting the /home line.

Comment: Well done. I am a bit humbled that I confused NIS Automounter setup for SIP. Great write up.