# How can I abort a High Sierra installation?

Tags: macos, upgrade, high-sierra

I am on Sierra now and I started High Sierra setup from the AppStore. I already opened the installer and passed all the steps and get "reboot to install" message.

The issue is that I realized that I cannot update just now as some of the work-related enterprise applications does not support the new version. Is there a way how can I abort installation at this step? I feel like sitting on a time bomb - once I reboot I will have all kinds of trouble with enterprise stuff.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be able to safely abort the install. Quit the installer without reboot. Then open Terminal.app and remove the installer folder (SIP has to be disabled to remove everything - most files and folders are deleted though, even when SIP is **enabled**!):

```
sudo rm -Rf /macOS\ Install\ Data
```

Then enter

```
sudo systemsetup -setstartupdisk /System/Library/CoreServices
```

A quick scan revealed that the only file/bundle installed/replaced (except some receipts) is /System/Library/CoreServices/MRT.app

Its version number is 1.23. The original file's version in macOS Sierra is 1.22. MRT is (Apple's) Malware Removal Tool.

---

If SIP is enabled I recommend to execute the steps above. Then immediately boot to Recovery Mode and [disable SIP](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-os-x-10-11). Then reboot **opening the Start Up Prefs and choosing your main volume**. Remove the remnants of the macOS Install Data folder (which should be possible now).

Reboot again to Recovery Mode and enable SIP again. Reboot to the main volume.

---

Apparently Sierra's MRT.app isn't available in any Sierra Combo updater. You would have to extract and re-install it using [Pacifist](https://www.charlessoft.com/) and the latest macOS Sierra installer.

High Sierra's MRT.app may also work in Sierra; so it's unclear whether installing the original version is really required.

Comment: Hmm.. It does not allow me to remove install folder:
`$ sudo rm -Rf /macOS\ Install\ Data
Password:
rm: /macOS Install Data/Locked Files/Boot Files: Operation not permitted
rm: /macOS Install Data/Locked Files/cleanup_installer: Operation not permitted
rm: /macOS Install Data/Locked Files: Operation not permitted
rm: /macOS Install Data: Operation not permitted`

Comment: Never mind. It looks like even folder is not deleted its content was deleted successfully. The only exception is contents of Locked Files. Is it OK to leave them there?

Comment: Ugh.. Looks like I have SIP enabled

Comment: thank you. It looks like my MRT.app has not been affected (last modification date is set to a date week ago. Wish me luck - will try to reboot in recovery and not trigger any kind of upgrade activity

Comment: Ok. I screwed up and failed to login in recovery mode. But your method still worked and upgrade has not been triggered even with leftovers in installation folder. Thank you once again!

Comment: When I enter single user mode (cmd+s) systemsetup command does not exist.  How can I get that command?