# How can I abort a Mojave installation?

Tags: mac, install, upgrade, mojave

I started the installation process for the Mojave upgrade from High Sierra but I realized I can't upgrade because of some incompatible enterprise software.
I would like to cancel it and prevent the installation when it restarts[image]

Comment: Did it format the drive and begin copying over?  If not, just force quit it (apple logo on the menu bar; top right of your monitor)

Comment: It completed the first step of the installation process, if I restart it will finish installing, which is what I would want to prevent to stay on High Sierra.

Comment: I would like to try this - [Abort High Sirerra upgrade](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/301236/how-can-i-abort-a-high-sierra-installation) -
but I don't know if it will work for Mojave

Comment: The steps should be the same.  You do have a back up, correct?

Comment: I do have a back up

Comment: Excellent!  Give the abort procedure a try and the worst that will happen is you have to restore from backup.