# How can I remove Chess from my mac?

Tags: terminal, macos, permission

I tried to remove Chess.app from my Mac:

- Moving to Trash: “Chess.app” can’t be modified or deleted because it’s required by macOS.
- Trying to change permissions for everyone in Get Info: The operation can’t be completed because you don’t have the necessary permission.
- chmod 755 Chess.app/ in Terminal works, but then doing sudo rm -rf Chess.app/: long list including rm: Chess.app/: Operation not permitted

So how can I remove it?

Answer (score 1):

Chess.app is, as everything else installed by default, protected by SIP and can't be removed. If you absolutely want to reclaim the 5mb used by the application you can

- Reboot into Recovery Mode to disable SIP
- Reboot normally, log in and remove Chess.app
- Reboot into Recovery Mode to enable SIP
- Reboot normally
- (and then repeat this with every macOS upgrade)

See [How do I disable System Integrity Protection (SIP) AKA "rootless" on OS X 10.11, El Capitan?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-os-x-10-11) for details about disabling/enabling SIP.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that it's only 5MB in size (although it's 8.8MB on High Sierra) :)

Comment: I always found it interesting that people want to get rid these pre-installed apps. If it's that they take up too much space or that they get in your way... well, either way I'm not sure I get it. I believe all pre-installed apps together take up ~2GB of your disk space. And you don't really need to ever see those apps depending on how you launch apps in general. I guess that is like 400 more  songs you could stuff in... or one movie.

Comment: @ScottEarle `du` says 4952 here (High Sierra 10.13.1 Beta), Finder says "7’885’411 Byte (5.1 MB on Volume)". Whatever that means :-)

Comment: @patrix The bundle is compressed transparently and occupies 5.1 MB of disk space. The (real) uncompressed bundle size is 7.9 MB.

Comment: Yeah I don't understand why so many sizes, either. My machine (also 10.13.1 beta 5) says 8,776,171 bytes (7.3MB on disk). I give up :)