# How can I simply and sustainably remove Chess from my macBook Air, Mojave?

Tags: macos, finder, applications, mojave

I have a list of applications I was interested in possibly removing as long as the OS does not need them to function.

For starters I want to remove **Chess** and **Stocks** as I never use them.  However when I right click on them on Finder, there is not option to delete.

I can't imaging that **Chess** is integral to the OS working so how can I delete it?

**I need it deleted it in such a way that when my computer automatically updates it does not show up again.**

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Also a duplicate of this: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/303657/88313

Please use the search function at the top of the page to see if your question has already been answered.

Comment: I updated the question to be more specific.

Comment: @J.M. As AdminHam said, the installer will always reinstall the 8MB Chess Application and reassert privileges. You will need to follow the instructions at the page marked duplicate after each update.

Comment: This is not a duplicate, as you can create a Launch Agent ...

Answer (score 0):

Tricky to keep them from coming back.. I would create a LaunchAgent to monitor the path(s) to the apps, & include a "sudo rm -r /path/to/app" command to delete them.

https://www.macissues.com/2015/02/02/how-to-use-launchagents-to-monitor-folder-contents-in-os-x/

You would likely have to keep SIP disabled (but even this can be re-enabled through OS updates!)