# How to launch pf at startup?

Tags: bash, launchd, firewall

I am looking for a pretty elegant way to launch the `pf` - a.k.a. Packet Filtering - process at startup. Using the `launchctl` or the `pfctl` commands, root privileges are required and so it is useless to add them into `.bash_profile`. Are there alternative solutions to this issue?

Comment: Can you explain what you're actually trying to accomplish? Pf might not even be the best way.

Comment: @Harv I’d like to block the outgoing connections that some applications establish on launch.

Comment: Check this out: http://www.hanynet.com/pflists/index.html, I'm guessing you ruled out Radio Silence, Little Snitch etc?

Comment: @Harv yes, because they are not free applications. pflist, on its side, is an open source project but seems to be not fully compatible with macOS Sierra - which I’m currently using - and next versions. Furthermore, it is nothing but an user-friendly interface of `pf`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to launch processes at startup using daemons. You can create a daemon - or even edit an already existing one - respectively adding or modifying a `.plist` file inside `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons` or `/Library/LaunchDaemons`.
In my case, running macOS Sierra, a daemon for `pfctl` was already located inside one of those folders but it was set up without the `-e` option; consequently, at startup the daemon was launched without any effect.
The issue has been solved adding that mentioned option, plus something more despite it is not properly necessary:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Disabled</key>
  <false/>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>com.apple.pfctl</string>
  <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
  <string>/var/run</string>
  <key>Program</key>
  <string>/sbin/pfctl</string>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>/sbin/pfctl</string>
    <string>-e</string>
    <string>-f</string>
    <string>/etc/pf.conf</string>
  </array>
  <key>RunAtLoad</key>
  <true/>
  <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
  <string>/var/log/pfctl.err</string>
  <key>StandardOutPath</key>
  <string>/var/log/pfctl.out</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 7):

By default pf is silenced at startup, a launch daemon *com.apple.pfctl.plist* exists though in /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/. To enable pf while booting you would have to add an `-e` switch in the plist.

Since all files in /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ are protected by SIP in macOS 10.11 and later you have to [disable it](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-macos-os-x) first.

Then, after booting to the main system, edit the launch daemon plist:

```
sudo nano /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.pfctl.plist
```

and replace

```
  ...
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>/sbin/pfctl</string>
    <string>-f</string>
    <string>/etc/pf.conf</string>
  </array>
  ...
```

with

```
  ...
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>/sbin/pfctl</string>
    <string>-e</string>
    <string>-f</string>
    <string>/etc/pf.conf</string>
  </array>
  ...
```

Reboot to Recovery Mode and enable SIP again.

Comment: My friend, this is indeed the best method, and I endorse your answer.

Comment: I don’t think it’s safe to edit system files like this. Your changes may not survive OS upgrades. Shouldn’t you create a launchctl job on a user level?

Answer (score 4):

> Are there alternative solutions to this issue?

Yes*, in System Preferences / Security & Privacy / Firewall Options..., check "Enable stealth mode" and turn on Firewall.

Somehow this enables PF. You can check by running `sudo pfctl -s info`.

*Tested on High Sierra and Mojave

Comment: This is the MVP answer right here, thank you

Comment: This is the simplest way to manage the PF startup which will survive to an OS upgrade and will avoid damage on `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/...`.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to mess about disabling System Integrity Protection (SIP), you can simply copy the existing file `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.pfctl.plist` to the unprotected user area `/Library/LaunchDaemons` giving it a slightly different name eg. `/Library/LaunchDaemons/my.netfilter.pfctl.plist`.

Then make your edits, I changed the Label name to match the filename and added the -e option as described in the other answers.

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key> <string>my.netfilter.pfctl</string>
    <key>Disabled</key> <false/>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key> <true/>
    <key>WorkingDirectory</key> <string>/var/run</string>
    <key>Program</key> <string>/sbin/pfctl</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>pfctl</string>
        <string>-e</string>
        <string>-f</string>
        <string>/etc/pf.conf</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

After reboot check it's running with `pfctl -s all`.
Tested on Mojave.

Answer (score 2):

**Enable PF via Console**

Here is how to enable your Mac Packet Filter (PF), and have it turn on automatically after each reboot. Other methods did not work for me.

Run the following from **Terminal** or via **SSH**:

```
sudo -i    
defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.alf globalstate -int 1
defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.alf stealthenabled "1"
/usr/libexec/ApplicationFirewall/socketfilterfw --setstealthmode on
```

Handy when working from home in a lockdown and have no access to GUI :-).
As sunknudsen has pointed out: stealth mode will enable PF to start automatically and stay on after reboots.

**Testing PF**

Reboot the computer (shutdown -r now) and after boot run the following command:

```
pfctl -s info
```

Look for a line that starts with "Status: Enabled". If it says that then the Mac Packet Filter is running.

Comment: Before running this command you need to ensure your firewall is turned on with `sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.alf globalstate -int 1`