# Can I simply make a partition on my Mac, install an OS to it, and boot from it via Startup Manner?

Tags: partition, startup, bootable-disk, multi-boot

On my Mac, can I simply create a new partition in Disk Utility, install an Operating System to it, such Arch Linux, and then boot from it by holding alt/option during boot (Startup Manager)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes, except the last one**:

> and then boot from it by holding alt/option during boot

Only Mac operating systems and sometimes Windows will show up in the menu. Instead I would suggest installing [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/). I have used it to dual boot Kali Linux and macOS Sierra on my MacBook Pro.

Very simple to install and use except you will need to [turn off SIP](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-macos-os-x) for the installation process.  You can turn it back on after.

**To Disable SIP**:

> 1. Reboot your Mac into Recovery Mode by restarting your computer and holding down <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> until the Apple logo
>      appears on your screen.
> 2. Click Utilities > Terminal.
> 3. In the Terminal window, type in `csrutil disable` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
> 4. Restart your Mac.

**Install rEFInd**

**Enable SIP**

> 1. Reboot your Mac into Recovery Mode by restarting your computer and holding down <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> until the Apple logo
>      appears on your screen.
> 2. Click Utilities > Terminal.
> 3. In the Terminal window, type in `csrutil enable` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
> 4. Restart your Mac.

Comment: It should be noted you can just install rEFInd from recovery mode itself, without ever having to disable SIP. 

EDIT: See http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/sip.html

Comment: @BaconDuctTape Yes, I totally forgot about that. Can you edit and provide instructions? I'm not exactly sure how to go about doing this. Or can you provide a link and I can edit it myself.

Comment: Don't you have to wait 30 seconds or something with rEFInd?

Comment: @keeganjk Not in my experience. It should immediately pop up when you boot and then boot into the OS when you make a selection. Can you provide a link to somewhere where it talks about this?

Comment: Just installed rEFInd and not having this problem. I think it meant that it starts after 30 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. On my Mac, even though I don't have OS X (I think its all the same though) you don't have to use option to boot into Ubuntu, but any other OS like OS X you will have to use Option to boot into it.
EDIT : Ubuntu or anything like Linux WILL NOT show up in the Option menu. It just boots straight away to Ubuntu.