# Installing ffmpeg from dmg and then running from a terminal, is there a better way?

Tags: terminal, install, bash

From here: https://ffmpeg.org/download.html#build-mac I chose static builds 64-bit which too me to https://evermeet.cx/ffmpeg/

I then downloaded this:

> [image]

and opened it using this:

> [image]

which gave me this:

```
Last login: Wed Jun  6 09:41:56 on ttys000
david-selfs-Air:~ david$ /Volumes/FFmpeg\ 91200-g1616b1be5a/ffmpeg ; exit;
ffmpeg version N-91200-g1616b1be5a-tessus Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.1)
  configuration: --cc=/usr/bin/clang --prefix=/opt/ffmpeg --extra-version=tessus --enable-avisynth --enable-fontconfig --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopus --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-version3 --pkg-config-flags=--static --disable-ffplay
  libavutil      56. 18.102 / 56. 18.102
  libavcodec     58. 19.104 / 58. 19.104
  libavformat    58. 17.100 / 58. 17.100
  libavdevice    58.  4.100 / 58.  4.100
  libavfilter     7. 24.100 /  7. 24.100
  libswscale      5.  2.100 /  5.  2.100
  libswresample   3.  2.100 /  3.  2.100
  libpostproc    55.  2.100 / 55.  2.100
Hyper fast Audio and Video encoder
usage: ffmpeg [options] [[infile options] -i infile]... {[outfile options] outfile}...

Use -h to get full help or, even better, run 'man ffmpeg'
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.
Deleting expired sessions...7 completed.

[Process completed]
```

However when I open a terminal and try `ffmpeg` or `man ffmpeg` or even `ffmpeg -i filename.mp4 -vn filename.wav`(from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2119127/3904031)) all I get is

> -bash: ffmpeg: command not found

I must be close, is there a place where I now need to define a path for `ffmpeg`? I don't know how to do that, or what path to use.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The problem is `bash` is looking for `ffmpeg` in directories list in the `$PATH`. Some of these directories are protected by SIP and therefore you would need to [disable SIP](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-macos-os-x) to put the file in these directories. Alternatively, you can install it using Homebrew.

First install HomeBrew with this command:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Then install `ffmpeg` with this command:

```
brew install ffmpeg
```

Homebrew will install ffmpeg in **a path not protected by SIP**, but within the `$PATH`, more specifically it will **install it under the  `/usr/local/bin` directory.**

**This can be done manually with manual commands** (basically manually doing what homebrew does. **For this approach check out @davids answer.** But I would suggest homebrew for multiple reasons. Its much easier to use and quicker to install a large amount of tools. You can also update much faster. Homebrew also makes installing dependencies easier.

**Edit:** I previously had a part of this answer with inaccurate information I have since changed it. I believe it is currently accurate. I have included the part about SIP because I think it is important to understand what restrictions there are regarding placement of commands and why there isn't just a single path for all commands.

Answer (score 27):

You are supposed to copy the program from the disk image to your local folders. The usual place for these things is /usr/local/bin

So:

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/bin
sudo cp /Volumes/FFmpeg\ 91200-g1616b1be5a/ffmpeg /usr/local/bin/
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg
```

and all should be good to go. Disabling SIP not required.

No need for homebrew or any other package handler to install a precompiled binary. You do need to read up on basic UNIX though.

Answer (score 2):

The terminal shell of macOS, as in Windows or Linux, is looking in the `$PATH` environment variable to locate binaries.

You can check your `$PATH` variable doing :

```
echo $PATH
```

Which outputs in standard recent macOS :

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

You either have to put a copy of the binary in one of those directory (preferably /usr/local/bin as it is not [SIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Integrity_Protection)-protected) or add another directory in your `$PATH` environment variable.

The best practice is generally to store your application elsewhere (e.g. `/lib`) and to only put a [symlink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) in the bin directory pointing to the binary itself. This is less true for self-contained binary but mandatory if you want to run an executable that resides inside an .app (e.g. `/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC`)

Comment: On macOS the canonical place for self-installed Unix binaries is `/usr/local` or more specifically `/usr/local/bin`,