# How can I permanently delete folders from /var/folders/ situated in Trash?

Tags: terminal, high-sierra, permission, recovery, trash

I recently encountered an error where none of the applications would open, similar to [this](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8149516). I was able to resolve the issue by using `Go to Folder...` option under the `Go` menu and navigating to `/var/folders/`. I deleted all the folders there and rebooted my system, after which everything is working normally.

The problem now that I'm unable to permanently delete the folders `fz` and `sv` from Trash. When I try to delete them, I get the following warning and no matter what I select, the folders are not deleted from Trash - `The operation can’t be completed because the item “0” is in use.`

*Note - MacOS has already replaced these deleted folders in /var/folders/.*

I've also tried deleting it from the terminal with super user permissions but still can't delete them -

```
Anish@Anishs-MBP:.Trash $ sudo rm -rf *
Password:
rm: fz/w4_v47p50v141vqr9pwtg9qc0000gp/0/SafariFamily: Operation not permitted
rm: fz/w4_v47p50v141vqr9pwtg9qc0000gp/0/com.apple.LaunchServices.dv: Operation not permitted
rm: fz/w4_v47p50v141vqr9pwtg9qc0000gp/0/com.apple.nsurlsessiond: Operation not permitted
rm: fz/w4_v47p50v141vqr9pwtg9qc0000gp/0/com.apple.routined: Operation not permitted
rm: fz/w4_v47p50v141vqr9pwtg9qc0000gp/0: Directory not empty
rm: fz/w4_v47p50v141vqr9pwtg9qc0000gp: Directory not empty
rm: fz: Directory not empty
rm: sv/tjz3fg0j3hx5_lhhmv335s0m0000gn/0/com.apple.LaunchServices.dv: Operation not permitted
rm: sv/tjz3fg0j3hx5_lhhmv335s0m0000gn/0/com.apple.nsurlsessiond: Operation not permitted
rm: sv/tjz3fg0j3hx5_lhhmv335s0m0000gn/0/com.apple.routined: Operation not permitted
rm: sv/tjz3fg0j3hx5_lhhmv335s0m0000gn/0: Directory not empty
rm: sv/tjz3fg0j3hx5_lhhmv335s0m0000gn: Directory not empty
rm: sv: Directory not empty
```

I've also rebooted the system in Safe Mode and tried to delete them but no luck.

I realize that there are operations being run tied with these files that's causing the problem. How do I find and stop these tasks so that I can delete these folders?

This issue is only with a single user account. It looks like I'll have to disable [System Integrity Protection](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/208481/230173) and then try to delete them. Is that safe? I'm using High Sierra if that matters.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Killing the processes did not work for me. They kept respawning making it impossible to delete them.

The only way I could empty Trash, as briefly mentioned in the question, was to temporarily disable System Integrity protection (SIP).

If anyone else faces the same problem, these are the steps -

1. You can disable SIP by following the numbered steps listed in [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/208481/230173).
2. After restarting your Mac, try opening *Trash* in *Finder* and clicking on *Empty*, which should hopefully delete the all of its contents.

***Important: Do not forget to enable SIP after emptying Trash*** -

1. Reboot your Mac in Recovery Mode and open Terminal, same as you did in Step 1 above.
2. In the Terminal window, type in `csrutil enable` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
3. Restart your Mac.

Answer (score 2):

If you can’t delete the file because a process is holding it open you could try killing the process and then deleting the file. To find the process try the command below

```
lsof | grep [path_to_file]
```

Then kill each process by ID with

```
kill -9 [id]
```

For `lsof` to give you the PIDs the file must be open when `lsof` is actually executing. If it’s being opened and closed extremely quickly by one or more processes then this approach may not work

There’s another way that’s more OSX friendly/specific which is the following command

```
sudo fs_usage | grep [path_to_file]
```