# How do I control the image display duration in the Mojave screensavers?

Tags: macos, mojave, screensaver

How do I adjust the display duration of images used in the Mojave screensaver?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You'll need to disable System Integrity Protection first(see [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-macos-os-x))(only need to do it temporarily)
2. Open Finder and hit <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>G</kbd> to open the "Go to..." window.
3. Paste in `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Slideshows.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Content` and hit "Go".
4. When changing system files, it's always a good idea to have a backup, so make a copy of the file `EffectDescriptions.plist` before editing it.
5. Open `EffectDescriptions.plist` in a text editor of your choice.
6. (Use <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> to find it faster) find the key entry `JustASlide`, then find the child entry `mainDuration` below it.
7. The default entry should be 3, and you can change this value to whatever you want.
8. Save the file(you may need to provide your username & password because it's a system file).
9. IMPORTANT: Enable SIP again by following the same steps to disable it, except instead of typing `csrutil disable`, type `csrutil enable`.

If you are unable to open/save the file after disabling SIP, try opening the application from the terminal using `sudo`(ex for TextEdit: `sudo /Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/TextEdit`)

Comment: @abd I replaces first entry of "mainDuration" to "10" and I got a black screen instead of screen saver slide show. Did I do something wrong? There was no mainDuration entry with value followed

Comment: the first entry of mainDuration is used in some kind of formula and used as variable. @ABCDEFGHGJKPQGQSde_needsRandomSeed[orientation_needsPanoInformationYclassNameWpresets]effectVersion_phaseInDurationZisNative3D_phaseOutDuration^imageInputInfo\mainDuration]numberOfTexts There is no mainDuration followed by integer in a whole file.