# How do I change the image display duration in the Catalina screensavers?

Tags: macos, catalina, screensaver

I am using macOS 10.15.2

I have tried: [OS X Mavericks screensaver changes pictures too quickly: How do I slow it down?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/135766/) and it doesn't work. Then I tried: [How do I control the image display duration in the Mojave screensavers?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/340484) Here I can not find the `mainDuration` default of 3 (Points 6 and 7) and therefore not change it.

I would like to make the image duration screen saver different. Is this possible?

Comment: I have tried: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/135766/os-x-mavericks-screensaver-changes-pictures-too-quickly-how-do-i-slow-it-down and it doesn't work. Then I tried: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/340484/how-do-i-control-the-image-display-duration-in-the-mojave-screensavers Here I can not find the mainDuration default of 3 (Points 6 and 7) and can therefore not change it. @ankii

Comment: @ankii - Thanks for letting me know.  I didn't read the full edit history but saw the orphaned link.  Nothing worse than guessing OPs intentions as that can send us all down the wrong road.

Comment: You should start by installing Xcode (check the App Store), then make sure you've disabled SIP as mentioned. Then open the file mentioned by doubleclicking it -- Xcode should now open. The JustASlide option is only the 4th item down the list, so it's easy to find. Opening that up you'll find mainDuration. It looks like you just change it from 3 to something else, like 10. Save the file, enter your username/password and then restart.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon this problem today. Even with 'csrutil' disabled I couldn't modify the screensaver. I found out Catalina double protect the user setting the volume as read only.

After disabling 'csrutil', do 'sudo mount -uw /' on terminal and you'd be able to modify it until restart.

Comment: Wow! That's a lot of work to accomplish something that Apple could have made much easier!

Comment: And now in Monterey, even this doesn’t work.