# Is there a way to adjust the speed of the slideshow screensavers in macOS Big Sur and above?

Tags: macos, permission, plist, screensaver, root

I find the slideshow speed too fast and would prefer a 15-30 second duration.

I'm looking for a solution for Monterey in particular but I think this applies to Big Sur as well, and maybe Ventura and beyond.

I know the relevant plist is at `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Slideshows.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Content/EffectDescriptions.plist` and I believe the key that needs changing is `mainDuration` in the `JustASlide` key. The terminal command below would work if the plist could be made user-writable.

```
sudo /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "set ':JustASlide:mainDuration' 10" /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Slideshows.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Content/EffectDescriptions.plist
```

I've found answers listed below helpful but I'm so far unable to fathom how to apply either of the potential solutions to the making the root filesystem writeable to this problem. I also don't want to risk not being able to use Filevault.

Working on the hunch that versions of the plists in /Library/ would override the ones in /System/Library/, I tried recursively copying `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Slideshows.framework/` to `/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Slideshows.framework/` and changing the destination plist, but this had no effect.

[OS X Mavericks screensaver changes pictures too quickly: How do I slow it down?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/135766/os-x-mavericks-screensaver-changes-pictures-too-quickly-how-do-i-slow-it-down)

[How do I change the image display duration in the Catalina screensavers?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/378905/how-do-i-change-the-image-display-duration-in-the-catalina-screensavers)

[Can I mount the root (system) filesystem as writable in Big Sur?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/395508/can-i-mount-the-root-system-filesystem-as-writable-in-big-sur)