# Disabling / Uninstalling iTunes on macOS Mojave

Tags: macos, itunes, keyboard, mojave, spotify

I'm using MacOS 10.14 Mojave on a MacBook Pro.

I'm trying to disable iTunes, mostly because it annoys me several times a day when I use my keyboard play/pause media button.

I have Spotify up and running and it usually gets these commands, but sometimes iTunes will pop out of nowhere (mostly when it's been a while without focusing the Spotify window).

I know in the past iTunesHelper process was responsible for this behavior and we could just disable it in the login items.

But today I have nothing in my login items, and no iTunesHelper process running.

The only suspect process I found was "com.apple.iTunesLibraryService", I tried to force kill it but it won't change anything.

Of course I tried to delete iTunes but it is "required by MacOS" -- seriously.

If I try to change authorisation on app to force uninstall anyway it tells me I don't have the required authorizations to do that -- as an administrator, right.

The only way to delete it seems to imply using some shady tricks that may or may not break my OS.

I'm seriously annoyed by the fact I can't own my laptop fully.

**How can I uninstall or disable iTunes on macOS?**

**Side note:** I will never connect any Apple device to my laptop, if that matters for iTunes sync or something.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1. [Disable SIP](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-macos-os-x)
2. Open /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app
3. Enter in `sudo rm -rf /Applications/iTunes.app`
4. Enter your password (it won’t be displayed on screen)

Comment: aaaand ... DONE. Thank you sir !
However, I have a feeling I'm going to have some funky updates in a near future 

Comment: This doesn't work for me. It's still installed and visible in Applications.

Comment: @MagnusLindOxlund does the terminal command give you any errors? Can you still go into iTunes.app/Contents? Did you restart?

Comment: Can SIP be re-enabled after uninstalling iTunes?  Will this cause the decaying corpse of iTunes to reanimate?

Comment: @intuited yes you can, I did

Answer (score -1):

Apple has ensured that iTunes CANNOT be deleted anymore.  rm fails.

Comment: This contradicts the answer already given...

Comment: Sure there is a lot of safeguards to prevent users from doing bad things with the OS. But At0mic's answer provide a way of removing it