# Repair iTunes (12.9.5) on Mojave (10.14.5)

Tags: macos, itunes, mojave

A few months ago, I successfully removed iTunes from my machine using the accepted answer for this question: [Disabling / Uninstalling iTunes on macOS Mojave](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/344059/disabling-uninstalling-itunes-on-macos-mojave)
In short, via the command

```
sudo rm -rf /Applications/iTunes.app
```

However, now I need it back for reasons. Turns out the latest Mojave update (10.14.5) brought iTunes back for it's currently sitting on my Applications folder; only that it won't launch. It will barely show up on the Dock before the OS shuts it down.

From the Console, I'm seeing the following errors every time I attempt to launch iTunes:

[image]

Among those, the inability to read/write this pref key `_DKThrottledActivityLast_DKKnowledgeStorageLogging_DKKnowledgeStorageDidInsertEventsNotification` is the most apparent.

Now, for there's no standalone installer for iTunes 12.9.x, I can't simply  remove and reinstall the program itself. Latest public installer is for iTunes 12.8.2 which won't install unless on "macOS version 10.13.99 or earlier".

I searched online and already turn to Apple Support for a solution and they all agree that a full Mojave reinstall is required to fix this, which I find unreasonable. I hoped that you may know better.

Comment: You could try running the Combo updater over it, or just reinstall the current OS from recovery - neither of which are destructive.

Comment: Yah, I'd make a Mojave USB installer, boot from that and just reinstall. That won't touch your files and will repair the install. I get it that iTunes sucks and sucks up RAM and disk space but this is a good example of why *not* to uninstall Apple's 'native' apps.