# How can I edit the default vimrc file? (it's read only, and chown and chmod says 'operation not permitted')

Tags: vi

How can I edit the default vimrc file on osx? (sudo chown ... gives Operation not permitted )

In osx vim `/usr/share/vim/vimrc` is the default vimrc file

My username is 'apple'

If I try to do `vim /usr/share/vim/vimrc` then it says 'read only'

~/.vim$ ls -l /usr/share/vim/vimrc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  532  5 Apr  2017 /usr/share/vim/vimrc
~/.vim$

If I try to change ownership of the file

```
~/.vim$ sudo chown apple /usr/share/vim/vimrc 
chown: /usr/share/vim/vimrc: Operation not permitted
~/.vim$
```

similarly with permissions (giving write access to non-root users temporarily for the purposes of me editing the file)

```
~/.vim$ sudo chmod 666 /usr/share/vim/vimrc
chmod: Unable to change file mode on /usr/share/vim/vimrc: Operation not permitted
~/.vim$
```

sudo chown does work on another file though, so it's not a password issue.

```
~/.vim$ cp /usr/share/vim/vimrc zzz
~/.vim$ ls -l zzz
-rw-r--r--  1 apple  staff  532  3 May 23:10 zzz
~/.vim$ sudo chown root zzz
~/.vim$ sudo chown apple zzz
~/.vim$
```

Comment: You should not overwrite the system vimrc for various reasons. One being that with a system upgrade it will be overwritten. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25273075/editing-my-vimrc-file-on-a-mac)

Comment: @modlin i'm only looking to change one line, and it's my computer. So even if it's not recommended to do so, I want to do so.  I'm asking how

Comment: What are you trying to change? There's probably a way to do this with a `.vimrc` file in your home directory, rather than making a change to a system file.

Comment: @duskwuff of course  it can be done from the file in the `~/.vim/vimrc`, but I want to change the file that runs first.  As to why, it's a personal preference that if one particular feature of vim is so utterly ridiculous, I want to turn it off in the main file. Then put my customizations in the home dir vimrc. Then if I have different vimrcs  can do vim -S a.a   or vim -S b.b (where a.a or b.b are vimrc files),  and they'll all run shortmess=I  from the main file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be a System Integrity Protection (SIP) issue. See [About System Integrity Protection on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899). Error message shown below is often displayed when SIP prevents a command from executing.

```
Operation not permitted
```

Basically, you need to either temporarily [disable SIP](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-macos-os-x) or edit the file while booted to [macOS Recovery](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314).