# How to delete pre-installed apps in Catalina?

Tags: applications, catalina, macos

I want to delete the pre-installed apps, like Music, Books, Siri etc. from my iMac running Catalina. How do I do this?

(NOTE: [This question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/363209/how-to-delete-pre-installed-apps-on-macos-catalina?noredirect=1&lq=1) asks the same thing but was closed as a duplicate of [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/362653/macos-catalina-file-structure-cannot-remove). Annoyingly, the supposed duplicate doesn’t give an obvious answer to the question, and the original was locked can’t be answered, hence a new question. I can’t add an answer to [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/65169/is-it-possible-to-delete-the-useless-apps-pre-installed-on-my-mac) either)

Comment: This [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/367679/115093) in your last linked question will work in Catalina (i.e. delete them from recovery).  So would disabling SIP and remounting root rw with `sudo mount -uw /`.  Ideally your first linked question (which this is a duplicate of) [How to delete pre-installed apps on macOS Catalina](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/363209/how-to-delete-pre-installed-apps-on-macos-catalina?noredirect=1&lq=1) would be re-opened as *it's* linked duplicate doesn't answer the question just explains the read only file system. We will see.

Answer (score 1):

Catalina introduced changes to the way the file system files are stored, i.e. it puts them on a separate read-only APFS volume. The pre-installed apps are also found on this partition. More details can be found in this [ars technica article](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2019/10/macos-10-15-catalina-the-ars-technica-review/11/#h1). In short, you need a slightly different method compared to previous versions to get at those pesky pre-installed apps.

(Information taken from [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/osx/comments/dfetr4/how_to_i_delete_default_apps_in_catalina/))

Boot into recovery by holding cmd + R while the system is booting

Open up terminal (found in one of the menus at the top), and type the command `csrutil disable`. This will turn off the SIP

Reboot into Catalina

In terminal run `sudo mount -uw /`

You should now be able to delete the pre-installed apps. I used AppCleaner to do this. It will let you delete them, but you'll have to click remove twice.

Boot into recovery again and in the terminal type `csrutil enable` to re-enable the SIP. I’m not sure if this step is necessary as some things I’ve read suggest that it is automatically re-enabled, but that’s what I did.

You should now find that the apps are gone.

Note: I have found that the apps can reappear, I suspect this might be related to updates, but I don’t know. You should always install updates, but you might have to delete these apps again after updating.

Comment: You really don't save any space as you can't *store anything* on the boot volume where the Apps reside. Also after you go to all the trouble/hassle of doing this, macOS updates usually put them right back where they belong. I just ignore them.

Comment: Deleting things is not always about saving space.