# How do I delete Notes.app on my macOS Catalina?

Tags: catalina

I've tried using chmod to modify permissions but I keep getting back "chmod: Unable to change file mode on Notes.app: Operation not permitted"

Anyone have any ideas?

Excluding it from Alfred search would also be a solution! I don't want to allow myself to use Notes.

Comment: Sorry if I understood wrong but can you please clarify this? a) Why are you running `chmod` on Notes.app if you want to delete it? b) Are you asking how to delete or how to exclude from alfred search

Comment: What happens when you just drag Notes.app to the Trash?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete pre-installed apps in Catalina?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/387756/how-to-delete-pre-installed-apps-in-catalina)