# Cant install bootcamp in MBR after internal SSD upgrade

Tags: bootcamp, partition, guid

I upgraded internal kSSD on my mac (MBP-2013) via Carbon Copy Cloner.

OSX loads fine, but for some reason I cannot boot into Windows that I have installed on external USB in MBR mode. Prior to changing the internal SSD the USB in MBR was booting fine. My

I do need to have Windows installed via BIOS/MBR to use external GPU. I tried installing via Virtualbox and via [unebootin](http://fgimian.github.io/blog/2016/03/12/installing-windows-10-on-a-mac-without-bootcamp/), but have the same result - when I restart MBP to continue Windows installation I see a cursor for a second and then the screen goes blank. Not black as if it was turned off but blank - the display is clearly working but there is nothing being displayed.

My latest steps:

1. Format USB as MBR/Fat32
2. Get to final stages of Windows 10 Installer in Virtualbox
3. Reboot hold ALT -> pick Windows
4. Blank screen

What can I do to get Windows installation to continue in MBR mode?

A note - if I format USB as GUID I can install and boot from USB windows just fine.

Comment: If I read you question correctly, you are saying you **had** Windows BIOS booting on a external USB drive. I did not think that was possible. Can post a comment to confirm or deny this?

Answer (score 1):

You could install [rEFInd](https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) as by default this will automatically identify legacy Windows installations on internal or external disks.

Alternatively you could create a [hybrid member](https://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/hybrid.html) on your internal SSD using [gdisk](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gptfdisk/) and set at least one partition bootable.

This will cause the firmware to initialize the BIOS/CSM/legacy support.

You can pick any partitions as macOS will ignore it when booting.  If you have EFI, Macintosh HD and Recovery you could pick 2 and 3.  For example :

1. `sudo gdisk /dev/disk0`
2. take option <kbd>r</kbd> for recovery menu.
3. take option <kbd>h</kbd> to create hybrid member.  Here partitions 2 and 3 are chosen with 2 set bootable.

```
Type from one to three GPT partition numbers, separated by spaces, to be
added to the hybrid MBR, in sequence: 2 3
Place EFI GPT (0xEE) partition first in MBR (good for GRUB)? (Y/N): Y

Creating entry for GPT partition #2 (MBR partition #2)
Enter an MBR hex code (default AF): AF
Set the bootable flag? (Y/N): Y

Creating entry for GPT partition #3 (MBR partition #3)
Enter an MBR hex code (default AF): AF
Set the bootable flag? (Y/N): N
```

4. take option <kbd>w</kbd> to write changes and exit.

Depending on your version of macOS you may need to [disable SIP](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-macos-os-x) to use either *gdisk* or install *rEFInd* but you can enable it again after.

Comment: Some of the values you show being entered into gdisk are wrong.