# Removing randomwhere, malware(leadingsignsearch) from [Security & Privacy] - [Full Disk Access]

Tags: security, malware

I know I should have cautioned when I first download unwarranted stuffs, but things happen.

Removing them from `/Library/LaunchDaemons` or `settings` of each browsers, anything manually are done. `Profile` cleared, but from this particular section:

[image: error]

`-` at the bottom of the right window will not work. It will not respond to the mouse click. As you can see, I have already unlocked.

Please someone let me know. I need these eradicated.

Comment: Try [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com/mac-download/) to see if it will help.

Comment: Can you just untick the checkmark?

Answer (score 1):

Try Apple's command line tool `tccutil`! The general usage is:

```
tccutil command service bundleIdentifier
```

Only one command (`reset`) is implemented right now. The service is the protected item (e.g. Microphone or Photos). The bundleIdentifier is the bundle identifier of the app given access to protected services.

1. Open Terminal
2. Get the bundleIdentifier of the apps to remove:

   ```
   mdls -name kMDItemCFBundleIdentifier -r /Applications/Some.app #Some.app is just an example.app
   ```

   Real example:

   ```
   host:~ user$ mdls -name kMDItemCFBundleIdentifier -r /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app
   com.apple.Terminal
   ```

   More methods to get the bundleIdentifier: [Getting the bundle identifier of an OS X application in a shell script](https://superuser.com/questions/346369/getting-the-bundle-identifier-of-an-os-x-application-in-a-shell-script). The app to remove is not necessarily in /Applications or /Applications/Utilities/.
3. Remove all permissions for the app:

   ```
   tccutil reset All bad.axisofevil.randomwhere #bad.axisofevil.randomwhere is just an examplary bundleIdentifier
   ```

RansomWhere?'s exec has a *(null)* bundleIdentifier. The associated launch daemon plist contains a `com.objective-see.ransomwhere` though, which looks like a typical  bundleIdentifier. I would try this one first.

BTW: RansomWhere? is no ransomware but a sec tool available here: [RansomWhere?](https://objective-see.com/products/ransomwhere.html)

---

**Alternative approach:**

Download *tccutil (v1.2.5)* from github. It's not related to Apple's command line tool though having the same name. It's also available via brew but apparently outdated there (v1.2.2) and won't work with Catalina.

1. [Disable SIP](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-macos-os-x)
2. Download *tccutil* from github.com/jacobsalmela/tccutil (direct link: [tccutil](https://github.com/jacobsalmela/tccutil/archive/master.zip))
3. Unzip the downloaded tccutil-master.zip
4. *tccutil* is a Python script.
5. In the command line enter (in the example below I d/led the zip to Downloads and unzipped it there - apply the path below to your environment respectively):

   -h to get a short help text

   ```
   sudo python $USER/Downloads/tccutil-master/tccutil.py -h
   ```

   -l to list all items in the accessibility database

   ```
   sudo python $USER/Downloads/tccutil-master/tccutil.py -l
   ```

   -r to remove an app/entry

   ```
   sudo python $USER/Downloads/tccutil-master/tccutil.py -r /path/to/example.app|bundleIdentifier
   ```
6. Enable SIP

Comment: This may be a dumb question, but am I supposed to write the term of malware in place of `Some`? I get the error `Some.app: could not find Some.app.` lol

Comment: You have to get the bundleIdentifier of  `LeadingSignSearch` and `RansomWhere?`. Some.app is just an example app. I can tell you the bundle identifier of the latter in a few minutes (after installing it in a VM). LeadingSignSearch is apparently not installed on any of my machines but I may get it (and its bundleIdentifier) soon - takes several ten minutes up to some hours.

Comment: removing from all the LaunchAgents and Daemons itself resolved most of the issue that I came back to trying your suggestion a little late. thank you for your help, it was just a little more complicated than the other.. Hope you dont get infected! @klanomath

Comment: @user12431122 The only reference to *LeadingSignSearch* I get (via Google) is your question. So no chance right now to fetch a possible bundleIdentifier for it.... I still have to look into another tccutil (provided by homebrew>github.com/jacobsalmela/tccutil) whether it offers more than Apple's tccutil

Comment: Thank you for sharing. Seems like it will be my intro to anti-virus setup of Mac

Comment: @user12431122 IMHO *LeadingSignSearch* is a randomized app/service name based on a larger wordlist. It will be tied forever to user12431122. Thank god this is neither your commonly used Internet alias nore your real name...

Answer (score 1):

```
tccutil reset SystemPolicyAllFiles
```

will reset all Full Disk Access apps' permissions. You'll have allow them once again.

https://c-command.com/spamsieve/help/security-privacy-acce

Comment: gosh, where do people locate these resources? do you happen to know how to toggle between web search results? A friend of mine showed how to do that, with arrows (>) appearing at the left of each item but it's not recreated nor searched..

Comment: Oh that’s kind:) I just browse this site. // Tab would do that. And to go back and forth in history, CMD and square brackets.

Comment: No thats not what Im looking for