# Revoke permission to run third-party kernel extension

Tags: macos, kernel-extensions

Once a user grants macOS permission to run a third-party's kernel extensions, all extensions signed by that developer's key are allowed to run. Even if the extension is erased and reinstalled, permission remains.

How does one subsequently **revoke permission** to run one or all third-party kernel extensions?

This is not a request for how to unload kernel extensions. Assume, for example, that a developer wishes repeatable QA around the process of installing and prompting a user to authorize a kernel extension.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [TN2459](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2459/_index.html)

> Approved KEXTs are tracked in a system-wide policy database through the team identifier in the KEXT's code signature and the bundle identifier from the KEXT's Info.plist, so updating a KEXT that has already been approved will not trigger a new approval request.

This database (at least until Mojave) is */var/db/SystemPolicyConfiguration/KextPolicy* and you can update it with sqlite3 after [disabling SIP](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/208481/115093).

```
A1398% csrutil status
System Integrity Protection status: disabled.
A1398% sudo sqlite3 /var/db/SystemPolicyConfiguration/KextPolicy
SQLite version 3.24.0 2018-06-04 14:10:15
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> .schema
CREATE TABLE settings ( name TEXT, value TEXT, PRIMARY KEY (name) );
CREATE TABLE kext_load_history_v3 ( path TEXT PRIMARY KEY, team_id TEXT, bundle_id TEXT, boot_uuid TEXT, created_at TEXT, last_seen TEXT, flags INTEGER , cdhash TEXT);
CREATE TABLE kext_policy ( team_id TEXT, bundle_id TEXT, allowed BOOLEAN, developer_name TEXT, flags INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY (team_id, bundle_id) );
CREATE TABLE kext_policy_mdm ( team_id TEXT, bundle_id TEXT, allowed BOOLEAN, payload_uuid TEXT, PRIMARY KEY (team_id, bundle_id) );
sqlite>
```

It contains 4 tables of which only *kext_policy* and *kext_load_history_v3* are interesting (unless you use mdm presumably).  For example these are my authorised kext:

```
sqlite> select * from kext_policy;
VBG97UB4TA|com.objective-see.lulu|1|Objective-See, LLC|1
Z3L495V9L4|com.intel.driver.EnergyDriver|1|Intel Corporation Apps|1
|com.rugarciap.DisableTurboBoost|1|Legacy Developer: Rugarciap|1
MLZF7K7B5R|at.obdev.nke.LittleSnitch|1|Objective Development Software GmbH|1
54GTJ2AU36|com.joshuawise.kexts.HoRNDIS|1|Joshua Wise|1
6HB5Y2QTA3|com.hp.kext.io.enabler.compound|1|HP Inc.|0
sqlite>
```

If you wanted to delete all of them you could use `delete from kext_policy;` then to be tidy `delete from kext_load_history_v3;`

Alternatively you can delete a specific one by comparing one of the fields shown by the `.schema` command.  For example to delete *LittleSnitch* based on the second field *bundle_id*;

```
sqlite> delete from kext_policy where bundle_id = "at.obdev.nke.LittleSnitch";
sqlite> delete from kext_load_history_v3 where bundle_id = "at.obdev.nke.LittleSnitch";
sqlite> select * from kext_policy;
VBG97UB4TA|com.objective-see.lulu|1|Objective-See, LLC|1
Z3L495V9L4|com.intel.driver.EnergyDriver|1|Intel Corporation Apps|1
|com.rugarciap.DisableTurboBoost|1|Legacy Developer: Rugarciap|1
54GTJ2AU36|com.joshuawise.kexts.HoRNDIS|1|Joshua Wise|1
6HB5Y2QTA3|com.hp.kext.io.enabler.compound|1|HP Inc.|0
sqlite> .quit
```

I notice that this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57499809/2953889) on stackoverflow suggests it may be necessary also to reset PRAM.  Resetting PRAM automatically reenables SIP and as it is easier than booting into recovery is worth doing.

---

It is possible to do this using a GUI if preferred. After disabling SIP:

- Download and install [DB Browser for SQLite](https://sqlitebrowser.org/dl/)
- Launch from terminal with `sudo /Applications/DB\ Browser\ for\ SQLite.app/Contents/MacOS/DB\ Browser\ for\ SQLite`
- Open Database */var/db/SystemPolicyConfiguration/KextPolicy* (press <kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> to show hidden files).
- On *Browse Data* tab in *kext_policy* table, right click and delete row(s) containing unwanted kexts.  Here I'm deleting kext for [LuLu](https://objective-see.com/products/lulu.html) firewall.
  [image: kext_policy]
- Change table to *kext_load_history_v3* and delete corresponding rows.
  [image: kext_load_history_v3]
- Click on *Write Changes*
- Reboot and reset PRAM (<kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>⌥</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd>) which will reenable SIP automatically with no need to boot back into recovery.

---

- After reboot a *System Extension Blocked* message is received for the kext whose records were deleted:
  [image: System Extension Blocked]
- Allowing software from the developer in *System Preferences* updates the *KextPolicy* database and then further reboots are back to normal.
  [image: System Preferences]

Comment: https://sqlitebrowser.org/dl/

Comment: Umm I don't know what to do with the database. But a GUI app is good for sqlite illiterate people like me. Also, I just browsed it after copying it out of there (required root password too), did no modifications.

Comment: @ankii - I added GUI option.  It is safe to test deleting things if you want.  If you delete a record for something in use then after reboot you'll get an error [System Extension Blocked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wT1DO.png).  If you then authorise it in [System Preferences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KloJL.png) it updates the database and next boot will be back to normal.