# I can't paste a file into system directory

Tags: terminal, mac, permission, java, copy-paste

I want to paste a file into /System/Library/Java/Extensions path but there is no "paste" button

[image: There is no paste button]. So I tried to change permissions, but when I checked I already have the permission to read & write. to this folder. Finally I tried to paste this file via Terminal. But this time it says "no such directory or file"

[image: No such file].

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: You can‘t copy data in `/System` and below. What do you want to accomplish here?

Comment: I need it for my electronic signature. It says I should do that in users Manuel.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-macos-os-x

Comment: Are the instructions you are following available in english, or can they be run through Google Translate? If yes, can you please add a link.

Comment: I suspect you could put the file in ~/Library/Extensions/Java/ See https://aldoblog.com/2002/05/where-to-put-java-extensions-on-mac-os-x/ I'm not a Java person. ymmv

Answer (score 5):

You have run into System Integrity Protection ( SIP ) which protects certain system folders from being changed.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899

To make the copy anyway, you turn off SIP.  Be sure to turn SIP back on when done. It's a hassle.

https://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac/how-turn-off-mac-os-x-system-integrity-protection-rootless-3638975/

I'd look for an alternative folder to place the file. I'm not a Java person.  I did find:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12842063/where-to-install-jar-files-on-os-x-so-other-java-applications-will-find-them

https://aldoblog.com/2002/05/where-to-put-java-extensions-on-mac-os-x/

Comment: Here's a relevant item in [Apple's old developer docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1170/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10001702-CH1-SECTION2). Summary: put extensions in `/Library/Java/Extensions` (which makes them available to all users on the computer) or `~/Library/Java/Extensions` (i.e. the parallel folder inside your home folder, which makes them available to just your account). BTW, starting in Catalina, SIP is reinforced by a split file system which prevents writing to /System even with SIP turned off.

Comment: @GordonDavisson You should post this as an answer.